# Kentico macro method inside template not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, macros, kentico

I have recently been working on Kentico sites, and the following issue has occurred recently, and never thought this won't work.

I have got a template on Kentico 8, and I want to display the content stored on 'ContentText' field of current document type.

So for this I am using the following code:

```
<cms:CMSDocumentValue runat="server" AttributeName="ContentText" FormattingString="{0}" />
```

which is working absolutely fine. However if I go and use a macro, as following:

```
<%# CurrentDocument.GetStringValue("ContentText", String.Empty) %>
```

it wouldn't pull the content stored on that field at all. 
Do anyone know where I am going wrong? I am pretty sure the syntax is correct.

The reason why I want to use the macro is because I may be using this to check whether the value is null or not, so I can change the visibility of a placeholder.

Hope someone can help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: You might try <%# IfEmpty(Eval("ContentText"),"",Eval("ContentText")) %>

Comment: @Jerreck .. As I mentioned above, this code is to go on the template, so Eval won't work at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kentico macros (K#) are not getting resolved automatically in page template markup. Also, K# is not allowed in data-binding expressions (`<%# ... %>`). Generally, in page templates you can resolve macros using the following code:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="CMS.MacroEngine" %>
<%= MacroContext.CurrentResolver.ResolveMacros("{% here comes your macro expression %}")%>
```

If I understand your question correctly you want to hide some asp:PlaceHolder control in the page according to value of current page field. This code might help you rather than invoking macro:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="CMS.DocumentEngine" %>
<script runat="server">
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    yourPlaceHolderControl.Visible = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.GetStringValue("Intro", String.Empty));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Eventually, you may want to resolve localization expressions such as `{$general.OK$}`. In this case you need to pass macro resolver settings with culture specification to `ResolveMacros` method. E.g. `ResolveMacros("expression", new MacroSettings() { Culture = CurrentDocument.DocumentCulture })`